# Flask SSE and Nginx not working properly

Tags: python, nginx, flask, server-sent-events

I'm facing the issue with SSE running on Nginx. I've one web app that I'm using Flask, and I'm using one module called `flask-sse` to send events to JS side.

I'm using `gunicorn` to process the requests, and I have this as Nginx configuration:

```
upstream backend {
        server 127.0.0.1:5000;
        keepalive 100;
}

server {
        listen 80;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/client-access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/client-error.log;

        location / {
                include proxy_params;
                proxy_pass http://backend;
                proxy_buffering off;
                proxy_cache off;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                chunked_transfer_encoding off;
                proxy_request_buffering off;

        }
}
```

The endpoint to receive the events are on `/stream`. And looking in the Nginx logs I've realized that the first connection to this endpoint is always a 504 error, as you can see here:

`10.2.2.254 - - [09/Apr/2018:09:06:14 +0000] "GET /stream HTTP/1.1" 504 585 "http://address/results" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36"`

This Nginx is running behind a gateway called Sophos (https://www.sophos.com/en-us.aspx). I don't if this could cause the problem, but when I run from my localhost everything works fine.

Also, what I think it is really strange, is that the first call, the one I posted above, is returning 504, but the subsequent calls returns 200, and this broke my mind.

Do you guys have any thoughts about how to solve this? Am I missing some Nginx configuration?

Thanks

Comment: 504 is Gateway Timeout. It presumably just means that the first request is taking too long to process.